# Naming tuple elements

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

I am developping a some kind of tuple structure, and I would like to allow the user to use its elements as fields,

**EXPLAINING :**

this is my tuple :

```
template<typename ...Ts>
struct myTuple{
   std::tuple<Ts...> data;

   template<size_t I>
   inline type<I>& get_t() {   // type<I> is the I'th type
      return std::get<I>(data);
   }

   // Other stuff
};
```

For the moment the user can have it this way :

```
struct UserStruct{
   myTuple<int,bool,string> t;
   // Other stuff
}
```

and use it like,

```
UserStruct ob;
ob.t.get_t<0>() = 0;
```

Which is a little bit complex... So i made it this way

```
struct UserStruct{
   myTuple<int,bool,string> t;

   decltype(mo.get_t<0>()) myInt() {
      return mo.get_t<0>();
   }

   decltype(t.get_t<1>()) myChar() {
      return t.get_t<1>();
   }

   decltype(t.get_t<2>()) myString() {
      return t.get_t<2>();
   }
};
```

so he can use it directly : myInt() = 0;

**My goal is that he could use the tuple as if he had an `int, bool, string` data members** without storing the references, which means I need a function ( or a functor ) to get the reference, so my solution is good, but it needs the user to define the functions. (And the getter looks much worse in the real code)

So I would like something like this :

```
struct UserStruct{
   myTuple<int,bool,string> t;

   MyFunctor<0> myInt;   //or an alias to a function

   MyFunctor<1> myChar;

   MyFunctor<2> myString;
};
```

Comment: Can you use C++14? It has `std::get<type>()`.

Comment: i am already using it, I added the tag

Comment: What if the tuple has 2 strings or 2 chars or 2 ints?  How will you distinguish between them?  I have a vague memory of Herb Sutter talking about future C++ version allowing aliases for std::get, so you can name the indices.  I'm not sure what the situation is with it though.

Comment: Well, the user can name them as he likes, myInt, myChar etc... are just examples

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun Sounds like youre trying to re-implement structs. Can't ‘*the user*’ just use a struct?

Comment: @Biffen Exactly, I kind of want to implement a struct using a tuple, I need the tuple

Comment: Why do you *need* tuples? To implement some kind of refection?

Comment: The need of tuples has nothing to do with the question, myTuple is a struct that can have any number of fields, that is why I use tuples, I use `int, char, string` in the example, but i may be 100 of them

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun maybe going the other way around and using [`BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html) could suit your needs.

Comment: @Quentin I don't how I could use it

Comment: This sounds like Eric Niebler's `tagged`.

Answer (score 2):

Code like `MyFunctor<0> myInt;` can't work without supplying t to the functor as well so it knows which tuple to link to.  You could, however, add a macro to build the accessor for you that would assume the tuple name is t (or you supply it to the macro).

```
#define LINK_MEMBER(ID, NAME) decltype(t.get_t<ID>()) NAME() {  \
  return t.get_t<ID>();                                         \
}
```

Then your code would look like

```
struct UserStruct{
   myTuple<int,bool,string> t;
   LINK_MEMBER(0, myInt);   //or an alias to a function
   LINK_MEMBER(1, myChar);
   LINK_MEMBER(2, myString);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use this until I find a solution without a macro

Comment: It occurs to me that you could also make a fancier macro for the entire body of the struct that you would call like `BUILD_MEMBERS(int, myInt, char, myChar, string, myString);`  Then it could assemble the tuple for you and you only have to worry about naming each entry and indicating it's type.  (This would look much better if I could span it over multiple lines.)

Comment: I would need a Macro with variadic arguments

Comment: Yes; it would limit you to 63 member variables in theory (since, by spec, macros cap out at 127 arguments), but in practice most compilers handle many more than that.  I've been thinking about pulling together a tuple-driven struct since it would allow for much easier reflection; if you're interested, I can make one and post a link.

Comment: Okay, I have something working here: https://github.com/mercere99/Empirical/blob/master/tools/tuple_struct.h  Note that this relies on macros.h in the same directory (in which I have many more generic macro tools).  I also have an example use case here: https://github.com/mercere99/Empirical/blob/master/UTests/tools/tuple_struct.cc   Note that I built these into my "Empirical" library, so I have "EMP" prefixes on everything.

Answer (score 0):

Why write `myInt()` when you can write `my<int>()`? It's one more character, and allows you to just write:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
struct myTuple{
    std::tuple<Ts...> data;

    template <size_t I>
    decltype(auto) my() { return std::get<I>(data); }

    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) my() { return std::get<T>(data); }
};

using UserStruct = myTuple<int, bool, std::string>;
```

No need for alias functions, macros, etc, while also being nice and concise.

Comment: myInt was just an example, What I meant is a way to let the user name the accessors. That is exactly the issue with tuple, it's that people want to give some meaningfull to the their variables not use get<I>

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun If you want to give meaningful names, just write a struct: `struct UserStruct { int myInt; bool myBool; string myString; };` Why do you even need a `tuple`?

Comment: It is a special structure, I need generectity